# Maintain a hashcode- (checksum-) file differentially

Tags: verification

Assume you have a file hierarchy with like a million files (could be a backup).

As described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/318530/generate-md5-checksum-for-all-files-in-a-directory
one could use any of the below commands to create a "checklist.chk" file with *hashcode* and *name* on each row:

```
md5sum * > checklist.chk        # Doesn't go down sub directories
# or
find -type f -exec md5sum "{}" + > checklist.chk   # Do go down sub directories
```

Then to check the files you can use:

```
md5sum -c checklist.chk
```

Now assume you have only changed a few of those million files (perhaps because you used rsync). Then it seams unnecessary to recalculate all the hashcodes.

I looking for something (a program, script or whatever) that uses a "checklist.chk" file with four columns: *hashcode*, *modification date*, *size* and *name* on each row. And much like rsync it skips files where the size/modification date hasn't changed.

Then at a later time you should of course actually check the integrity of the files by calling something corresponding to '''md5sum -c checklist.chk'''.

Or are there better ways to solve this whole problem.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: It's hard to understand what you don't just use `rsync`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If you use the --checksum in rsync it calculates a checksum for each file which becomes like 50 times slower in my experience.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Also the sender side may also become corrupt. What I want is to be able to check the integrity of both the sender and receiver side.

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote my own program: https://github.com/emandersson/hashcodefilesync that does the above (speeds up the updating of the hashfile).